# Email auth backend breaks django-social-auth

Tags: django, authentication, django-socialauth

I recently added an extra authentication backend to allow users to login using either their email address or username, but it seems to break django-social-auth since after enabling it, when I try to login through Facebook, I get the message `Incorrect authentication service`

The backend's code is:

```
class EmailBackend:
    supports_object_permissions = False
    supports_anonymous_user = False
    supports_inactive_user = False 

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if email_re.search(username):
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        else:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I got the code snippet from [Django snippets](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2463/)

My AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'apps.members.backends.EmailBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used an email auth backend with django-social-auth. I don't remember having done anything special for it to work so it might be something non obvious, here are the only differences I can see with my code :

I had my Email backend defined first in he list of `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, which may have some importance here.

I did not define any of the `supports_object_permissions` `supports_anonymous_user`  `supports_inactive_user`.

Comment: interesting  I'll see if that tip helps..though I'd already switched to [Django Email Auth](https://github.com/strange/django-email-auth)

Comment: that suggestion didn't help, but thanks for the help...for now I'll just mark your response as the answer.  I still the the email-auth app working well anyways...if it ain't broken don't mess with it